# How to filter data from from sql table?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table like this.

| epfno | designation |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | HELPER - BELT |
| 11 | CANTEEN HELPER |
| 12 | ABC HELPER XYZ NEW |
| 13 | XYZ HELPER NEW |

Now I need to filter all the helpers by using 'HELPER' word. How can I get my data?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) operator to get your expected result:

```
SELECT epfno, designation
FROM TableName
WHERE designation LIKE '%HELPER%'
```

if you are need the results ending with `HELPER` then try `LIKE '%HELPER'` and
if you are need the results starting with `HELPER` then try `LIKE 'HELPER%'`

Answer (score 2):

You need to rethink your table structure.
What you have here breaks the *most basic* of Data Normalisation Rules, namely that you should only have one value in any one field.  Here, you have multiple values (e.g. 'ABC', 'HELPER', 'XYZ' & 'NEW') in one field and that's a problem.

Any search you do on this field will likely use a Table Scan, because it has to read each and every row in order to find the value you want "buried" somewhere inside the field's value.

You need to break out these values into a new table, with one row per value:

```
+-------+-------------+
| epfno | designation | 
+-------+-------------+
|    10 | HELPER      | 
|    10 | BELT        |
|    11 | CANTEEN     |
|    11 | HELPER      | 
|    12 | ABC         | 
|    12 | HELPER      | 
|    12 | XYZ         | 
|    12 | NEW         | 
|    13 | XYZ         | 
|    13 | HELPER      |
|    13 | NEW         |
+-------+-------------+
```

Armed with this table (and some suitable indexes), finding those who are "HELPER"s becomes simplicity itself (and far, *far* more efficient for the database to process):

```
select efpno 
from TableName 
where designation = 'HELPER' 
order by 1 ; 

+-------+
| epfno |
+-------+
|    10 |
|    11 |
|    12 |
|    13 |
+-------+
```